# Use Snort to limit or prioritize application bandwidth usage

Tags: network, snort

Short version of a long story, we've been using bluecoat packetshapers for bandwidth control on a multi-tenant network. We like it because it allows us to divide the bandwidth equally, but still allow for bursting from one site when the bandwidth isn't contested.

Additionally, we use it to identify application flows from within the tenants on the network and can prioritize real-time protocols for them over less sensitive traffic like MS Updates, iTunes content, etc.

We are looking for an opensource alternative. It looks like I could perform the inspection using Snort in combo with OpenAppID. OpenAppID looks like it is receiving regular updates so I think it will be able to do a decent job of traffic identification. However, I can't tell if there is anyway within Snort to place bandwidth limits or priority levels on identified traffic flows. It can obviously block connections, but we aren't looking to block traffic, just throttle it. Anyone know if this is possible in Snort, or another opensource project I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Although you are looking at snort, this isn't a security question.

Comment: You are looking for QoS solutions. Once you use this term, searches return some options for you: https://user.xmission.com/~hidden/aatqos/

Answer (score 0):

Snort is designed for Network Intrusion Detection. For bandwidth shaper, you need to get a firewall system. Products you can try:

1. pfsense
2. wfilter NG firewall
3. untangle